# cURL connection time gives duplicate values

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to get a value of how long it takes to connect to a specific url using cURL. In this code i have a list of urls in an array ($imoniusarasas), and using cURL i am trying to get the connection time for each url:

```
foreach($imoniusarasas as $url1) {
$curl1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_URL, $url1); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS , 400);
curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS , 400); 
curl_exec($curl1);

$contime1 = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME);

 $imones[$url1] = array( 
                        'conn_time' => $contime1
                       );
```

}

I then put results into a table:

```
<?php foreach ($imones as $url => $times) { ?> 
                <tr>
                  <td align=center><?php echo $times['conn_time']; ?></td>
                </tr>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

My problem - it displays same values for multiple urls (if i put 10 urls in my array, it would display only 3 or 4 unique results, the rest would have same value) is this supposed to be like this or am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: Maybe all of those took same time? Try `CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME`

Comment: Thank you, i changed CURLINFO_CONNECT_TIME to CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME and it shows much better results now (no duplicates and more realistic numbers)

Comment: Great, connect  times can be same for many URLs, they don't represent the actual transfer time